# stripe.confirmCardPayment() not sending CardElement values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

i'm stucked on this part since the week before.
I have this:

```
export const CreditCardForm = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <CheckoutForm amount={props.gems} />
      </Elements>
    </>
  );
}
```

And inside CheckoutForm I have this form:

```
<form className="card card-body"  style={{}} onSubmit={handleSubmit} action='@Request.Form["continue_url"]' method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        id="panel1a-header"
      >
        <Typography><label htmlFor="card-element">{t('gems.card')}</label></Typography>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        <CardElement />

      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
    <Button disabled={!stripe} variant="contained" onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
      sx={{
        marginTop: "10px",
        backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right, #169ECB, #7C669E,#DD5373,#E5A572 )",
        borderRadius: "10px",
        padding: "5px 32px"
      }}>
      {t('gems.pay')}
    </Button>
    <DynamicDialog open={openOk} close={handleCloseOk} text={t('dynamicdialog.gems.bought')} />
      <DynamicDialog open={openError} close={handleCloseError} text={t('dynamicdialog.gems.error')} />
  </form>
```

Where I have a CardElement to save the Card information.

I execute paymentIntent.create() in my backend and it's doing correctly,
[this I can see in dashboard.stripe:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQVto.png)

I'm trying to confirm the payment like this:

```
const { error, paymentMethod: {status} } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(response.paymentIntent.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
      })
```

But I'm receiving this error when this function was executed:

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3LMoCCBcC6w1iPgO19pOU6tb/confirm 404
```

If I do this API call from Postman to get the completely response, I recieve this message:

```
"message": "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method."
```

The problem that I'm having if I'm not misreading is when I'm calling the function elements.getElement(CardElement) to put it inside the function stripe.confirmCardPayment() showed before.

I'm not sure if I do a `console.log(element.getElement(CardElement)`, what is printing is this:
[console log of CardElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thUt4.png)

I will be grateful if someone can help me with that, if you need more information or more part of my code I will publish what you need.

Thank you

Edit:

CreditCard.js

```
import {  Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Avatar, styled } from '@mui/material';
import stripeApi from '../utils/api/pay'
import { useLocalStorage } from '../utils/useLocalStorage';
import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm'

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_51KYq9ELsTxDutkYQKQ1rkl6AtHGVEwm0QsawsgcVYaob4ATxUx8I0wVAt5J0R2KQGgsckC6DhIPHdPaILZHfaluV003GIkkZ3O');
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szRNm8mDrNY
export const getServerSideProps = async (e, amount) => {
  const [tokenStorage, setTokenStorage] = useLocalStorage('token', '');
  const paymentIntent = await stripeApi.buyGems(`/payment/checkout`, {paymentMethod: {}, amount: 'amount.amount'}, tokenStorage)
  return {
      paymentIntent: paymentIntent.paymentIntent    
  }
}

export const JewelAvatar = styled(Avatar)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: "32px",
  height: "auto"
}));

export const CreditCardForm = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <CheckoutForm amount={props.gems}/>
        
      </Elements>
    </>
  );
}
```

export default CreditCardForm;

CheckoutForm.js

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe, Elements,PaymentElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import axios from "axios";

import { Avatar, styled } from '@mui/material';
import stripeApi from '../utils/api/pay'
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { useLocalStorage } from '../utils/useLocalStorage';
import { useStateValue } from '../context/StateProvider';
import { actionTypes } from '../context/reducer';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import DynamicDialog from './DynamicDialog/DynamicDialog';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import Stripe from 'stripe';


 const CheckoutForm = (amount) => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const [tokenStorage, setTokenStorage] = useLocalStorage('token', '');
    const [userStorage, setUserStorage] = useLocalStorage('user', {});
    const [paymentIntentIdStorage, setPaymentIntentIdStorage] = useLocalStorage('paymentIntentId', '')
    const [{user, token}, dispatch] = useStateValue()
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {t} = useTranslation()
    const [openOk, setOpenOk] = useState(false);
    const [openError, setOpenError] = useState(false);

    const handleCloseOk = () => {
      setOpenOk(false)
    }
  
    const handleCloseError = () => {
      setOpenError(false)
    }
  
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(amount)
      const response = await stripeApi.buyGems(`/payment/checkout`, {amount: amount.amount}, tokenStorage)
        
        
      // });
  
        try {
        const card =  elements.getElement(CardElement)
        
        console.log(card)

          const { error, paymentMethod: {status} } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(response.paymentIntent.client_secret, {
            payment_method: {
              card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
          })
          
          
          if(error) throw new Error(error.message);
          if(status === 'succeeded'){
            alert('ok')
          } 
          let userEdited = {}
          userEdited = userStorage;
          // userEdited.bits = userEdited.bits + paymentIntent.gems;
          setUserStorage(userEdited)
          dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
            user: userEdited
          })
          elements.getElement(CardElement).clear();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          setOpenError(true)
        }
        
      
    };
  
    
    return (
      <form className="card card-body"  style={{}} onSubmit={handleSubmit} action='@Request.Form["continue_url"]' method="POST" id="payment-form">
        <Accordion>
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel1a-header"
          >
            <Typography><label htmlFor="card-element">{t('gems.card')}</label></Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <CardElement  className="form-control" />
  
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
        <Button disabled={!stripe} variant="contained" onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
          sx={{
            marginTop: "10px",
            backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right, #169ECB, #7C669E,#DD5373,#E5A572 )",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            padding: "5px 32px"
          }}>
          {t('gems.pay')}
        </Button>
        <DynamicDialog open={openOk} close={handleCloseOk} text={t('dynamicdialog.gems.bought')} />
          <DynamicDialog open={openError} close={handleCloseError} text={t('dynamicdialog.gems.error')} />
      </form>
    );
  };

  export default CheckoutForm
```

API Endpoint:

```
import HttpException from '@/mow/shared/domain/exceptions/http';
import { pool } from '@/mow/shared/infrastructure/database';
import Stripe from 'stripe'

class PaymentRepository {
    public async pay(price: number): Promise<{} | HttpException> {
      try{
        const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_51KqhuBBcC6w1iPgOgQcQGgIjxd4wlcpjpD7TGMqGfIsJS6SObfbagDlvXRNpbA330kbfJtpdeIKHMu3ol2qZpX9A00o8gk7zoc', {
            apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
          });
        const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: price * 100,
            currency: 'EUR',
            description: 'Bits',
  
          });
          let paymentIntent
        
        return payment;
    } catch (error: any){
      console.log(error);
      return new HttpException(500, error.message);
    }
  } 
   
}

export default PaymentRepository;
```

Comment: Is `elements` defined in your `CheckoutForm` component (via `useElements`)? Is there a reproduction of this I can try out somewhere?

Comment: Yes I'm using useElements and useStripe in CheckoutForm.
And no sorry, I don't have any reproduction but I'm going to update right now the post and put it all my 2 files, and the API endpoint so you will have more information.